# Easiest way to create a patterned material without a specific overlap texture

Tags: texturing

[image: Texture Reference]

I'd like to create an image texture for the diamond style floor. Is the only way to do this to create geometry that mirrors this pattern and then texture accordingly? When I tried to texture with a simpler approach I ran into an issue. I used one diamond as a reference and created a tiled texture from it. However I immediately noticed that there were double black borders as a result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to create a tileable texture by baking from geometry - there is no easy way. A more advanced way to do it is shown in a youtube video series by stym. [GAME ASSET TUTORIAL - Tileable ground texture - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GA5XUK2nqEw) and [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmTxjrvHKXU).